# How many different ways can the 19 people be split across 3 cars such that no two cars have the same number of people?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are 19 people who are riding a rollercoaster and each time the rollercoaster runs with all 19 people they are organized differently among the 3 separate cars on the track. Each car can carry more than 19 people. We can see the coaster from far away, so we can see the number of people on each coaster car but the people themselves are indistinguishable. How many different ways can the 19 people be split across the 3 coaster cars on the ride such that no two cars have the same number of people?

So far I have figured out that using the concept of multisets the total number of ways to distribute 19 people among 3 cars would be:
$$\binom{21}{2}$$

Now I am not able to figure out how do I go about calculating the number of ways such that two cars have the same number of people and so then I can simply subtract it from the above expression and get the final answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note:  in these problems, one usually uses "people" as the objects to indicate that the "objects" are distinguishable.  Here I guess you aren't doing that, but that seems likely to be confusing.  Why not just say you have $19$ indistinguishable balls that you are placing in $3$ distinguishable urns?  Subject, of course, to the constraint that no two urns contain the same number of balls.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I am not able to figure out how do I go about calculating the number of ways such that two cars have the same number of people ...

Let the number of people in the three cars be $(x, x, y)$.

$$2x + y = 19$$

Clearly, $2x$ can take any **even** value from $0$ to $18$ (inclusive). So, $2x$ can take any of the $10$ possible values. And for each value of $2x$, $x$ and $y$ each will have a unique value.

But since the three cars are distinguishable, we'll have to multiply by ${3 \choose 2} = 3$. Any two of the three cars can have the same number of passengers.

Putting it all together, the number of ways such that two cars have the same number of people would be $10 \times 3 = 30$.